# Reading data by new versions of protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, compatibility

For a data which is produced by Protobuf 2.5.X, is it safe to read it by Protobuf version 3.0.X?

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf wire format is designed to be backward and forward compatible. So [generally it is safe](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#using-proto2-message-types), unless you shot yourself in the foot with one specific v2 feature: [custom default values](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#optional). Default values are [constant in v3](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#default). Specifically enum default value is the first entry and [it must be zero](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum). So your v2 custom values will be lost - fields of default value do not appear on the wire at all, so the receiver has no idea whether it was not set or was set to default value. Mind that in v3 all fields are `optional` (no more `required`), so any field can be legally missing.

If you haven't used custom defaults in v2, or nonzero value for the first enum entry, v3 should read it just fine.

Comment: To clarify, even if you used default values in v2, you can still read messages in v3 -- it's just that the defaults are now all zero. So if the field wasn't set by the sender, then its value will be zero on the receiving end. And there's no way to distinguish this from the field having been set explicitly to zero by the sender, because (as I understand it) the "has" accessors have been removed.

Comment: What about if I am using proto2 syntax in both cases? only upgrading the jars, but using the old syntax?